# scala cats traverse for list

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-cats

I am trying to understand the traverse for list using this page,
https://www.scala-exercises.org/cats/traverse

and I have a very basic question (sorry for those who think it is too easy or obvious).
just check below signature

```
trait Traverse[F[_]] {
  def traverse[G[_]: Applicative, A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => G[B]): G[F[B]]
}
```

```
import cats.data.{ NonEmptyList, OneAnd, Validated, ValidatedNel }
import cats.implicits._

def parseIntEither(s: String): Either[NumberFormatException, Int] =
  Either.catchOnly[NumberFormatException](s.toInt)
```

```
List("1", "abc", "3").traverse(parseIntEither).isLeft should be(true)
```

you can see the signature traverse is expecting 2 arguments, the first argument to be a List, and the 2nd argument to be the 'f'.
then why the above is calling it only with 1 argument? and instead the list becomes the 'instance'/'object' that the traverse method is called upon.

I am puzzled.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because if you have (n+1)-parameter method `foo`

```
class Arg1
class Arg2
  
object Obj {
  def foo(arg1: Arg1, arg2: Arg2) = ???
}
```

you can define a syntax (extension method, e.g. with the same name `foo`) delegating a call to the former `foo`

```
implicit class Arg1Ops(val arg1: Arg1) extends AnyVal {
  def foo(arg2: Arg2) = Obj.foo(arg1, arg2)
}

    // which is basically the same as
//  class Arg1Ops(val arg1: Arg1) extends AnyVal {
//    def foo(arg2: Arg2) = Obj.foo(arg1, arg2)
//  }
//
//  implicit def toArg1Ops(arg1: Arg1): Arg1Ops = new Arg1Ops(arg1)
```

and call `foo` as a n-parameter method on the first parameter as a caller

```
val a1 = new Arg1
val a2 = new Arg2

a1.foo(a2)
```

In your example `List("1", "abc", "3")` is like `arg1` and `parseIntEither` is like `arg2`.

In Cats `Traverse` is annotated with [Simulacrum](https://github.com/typelevel/simulacrum) [macro-annotation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html) `@typeclass`

[Traverse.scala](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/Traverse.scala)

```
@typeclass trait Traverse[F[_]] extends Functor[F] with Foldable[F] with UnorderedTraverse[F] { ...
```

and this annotation generates a syntax for `Traverse`

[syntax/package.scala#L64](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/syntax/package.scala#L64)

```
object traverse extends TraverseSyntax
```

[syntax/traverse.scala](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/syntax/traverse.scala)

```
trait TraverseSyntax extends Traverse.ToTraverseOps
```

*Traverse.scala*

```
object Traverse extends scala.AnyRef with java.io.Serializable {
  ...

  // macro-generated code
  trait Ops[F[_], C] extends scala.AnyRef {
    ...
    def traverse[G[_], B](f : scala.Function1[C, G[B]])(implicit 
      evidence$1 : cats.Applicative[G]
    ) : G[F[B]] = { /* compiled code */ }
    ...
  }

  // macro-generated code
  trait ToTraverseOps extends scala.AnyRef {
    @...
    implicit def toTraverseOps[F[_], C](target : F[C])(implicit 
      tc : cats.Traverse[F]
    ) : Traverse.Ops[F, C] { type TypeClassType = cats.Traverse[F] } = 
    { /* compiled code */ }
  }

  ...

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following equivalent ways of invoking `traverse`

```
implicitly[Traverse[List]].traverse(List("1", "abc", "3"))(parseIntEither)  // scary
Traverse.apply[List].traverse(List("1", "abc", "3"))(parseIntEither)        // a bit better
Traverse[List].traverse(List("1", "abc", "3"))(parseIntEither)              // much better
List("1", "abc", "3").traverse(parseIntEither)                              // what I ideally want to write
```

In all cases we need to access the evidence that `List` satisfies the constraints of `Traverse` type class before we can call `traverse`. We could be very explicit about it by using `implicitly` as in the first case, but ideally we want to just invoke `traverse` on a value without worrying too much about the type class mechanics as in the last case. The last case makes use of Scala facility called *extension methods*. Scala 3 has some [new syntax](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/extension-methods.html) which IMO really clarifies the extension concept. In Scala 2 they are implemented using `implicit class` construct which perhaps is not very informative as a keyword to beginners first encountering the concept. In Scala 3 the concept of extension methods can be tied to the concept of type class directly, perhaps something like so

```
trait Traverse[F[_]]:
  extension [G[_]: Applicative, A, B](fa: F[A]) def traverse(f: A => G[B]): G[F[B]]
```